# Rendering error in Android's image view by using custom made png file

Tags: android, rendering, png, android-imageview

I have a very strange error related to custom image Views in Android using self-made png files. This error might be difficult to debug. Still I just wanted to ask you guys here before not using the custom image view.

So I have the following image view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="22dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/window_open_no_arrows"
        android:width="45dp"
        android:height="45dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
</layer-list>
```

Here is the screenshot of it
[image]

I create an Image View out of it using the following code:

```
final ImageView flyingButton = new ImageView(getContext());
flyingButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flying_button_air_1);
```

and I animate it (so it flys through the screen). Actually the code is quite complicated, so I can't show it to you. But what you need to know is that depending on the drwable specified in this line `android:drawable="@drawable/window_open_no_arrows"`, everything works fine or I get a unspecified error message and the app crashes (here an extract of it):

```
 A  GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/pipeline/skia/SkiaOpenGLPipeline.cpp:127
2023-08-21 10:46:59.626 22025-22051 om.example.gam          com.example.game                     A  runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting...
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] Dumping all threads without mutator lock held
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] All threads:
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] DALVIK THREADS (14):
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] "RenderThread" prio=10 tid=18 Runnable
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x132c06d8 self=0xdd591810
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=22051 nice=-10 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xbbdb01e0
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=R schedstat=( 70660625928 3318920954 65423 ) utm=455 stm=6610 core=1 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xbbcb5000-0xbbcb7000 stackSize=1008KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00542d9e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+110)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 006a0897  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+1015)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 0069a171  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+65)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 006c61b4  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+1172)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 006bf266  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+630)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 006be1ce  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)+2446)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #06 pc 0065227d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpAllThreads(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*) const+445)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #07 pc 0063984f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1967)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #08 pc 00025a23  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libartbase.so (std::__1::__function::__func<void (*)(char const*), std::__1::allocator<void (*)(char const*)>, void (char const*)>::operator()(char const*&&)+35)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #09 pc 0001588f  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+79)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #10 pc 00006dbd  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+285)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #11 pc 0024dd11  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::swapBuffers(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, bool, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfo*, bool*)+145)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #12 pc 00257e78  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+1112)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #13 pc 0025ab5f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+767)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #14 pc 0024542d  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+285)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #15 pc 0026cabf  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+127)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #16 pc 00015116  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+374)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #17 pc 000147d9  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+457)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #18 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #19 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   (no managed stack frames)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] 
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Native
2023-08-21 10:46:59.626 22025-22051 om.example.gam          com.example.game                     A  runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x7233bc28 self=0xdd583810
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=22025 nice=-10 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xeb954478
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=S schedstat=( 9562624174 4586979131 37249 ) utm=764 stm=191 core=3 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xff229000-0xff22b000 stackSize=8192KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes=
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00000b97  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+7)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 0005ad68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (syscall+40)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 0007725e  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__futex_wait_ex(void volatile*, bool, int, bool, timespec const*)+142)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 000e5b2e  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (pthread_cond_wait+62)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 0025a146  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::DrawFrameTask::postAndWait()+182)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 0023922d  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::android_view_ThreadedRenderer_syncAndDrawFrame(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, _jlongArray*, int)+109)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.graphics.HardwareRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame(Native method)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.graphics.HardwareRenderer.syncAndDrawFrame(HardwareRenderer.java:433)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:658)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4101)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] 
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] "Signal Catcher" prio=10 tid=6 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x132c0228 self=0xdd58a810
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=22035 nice=-20 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xd27e21e0
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=S schedstat=( 324261 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xd26e7000-0xd26e9000 stackSize=1008KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes=
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00000b99  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 000ce821  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+33)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 00086c55  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (sigwait+69)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 00665f1d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::WaitForSignal(art::Thread*, art::SignalSet&)+461)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 006648ff  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+479)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #06 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   (no managed stack frames)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] 
2023-08-21 10:46:59.626 22025-22051 om.example.gam          com.example.game                     A  runtime.cc:655] "perfetto_hprof_listener" prio=10 tid=7 Native (still starting up)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x0 self=0xdd586210
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=22036 nice=-20 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xd26e11e0
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=S schedstat=( 453304 0 8 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xd25e6000-0xd25e8000 stackSize=1008KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes=
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00000b97  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+7)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 000ccf9c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (read+28)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 0001aca2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libperfetto_hprof.so (void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, ArtPlugin_Initialize::$_29> >(void*)+306)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   (no managed stack frames)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] 
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] "ADB-JDWP Connection Control Thread" prio=10 tid=8 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x132c02a0 self=0xdd588c10
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=22037 nice=-20 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xd25e01e0
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=S schedstat=( 1278972 202074 9 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xd24e5000-0xd24e7000 stackSize=1008KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes=
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00000b99  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 000cf496  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__ppoll+38)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 00083979  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (poll+105)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 0000a493  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libadbconnection.so (adbconnection::AdbConnectionState::RunPollLoop(art::Thread*)+1171)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 000086d2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libadbconnection.so (adbconnection::CallbackFunction(void*)+1666)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #06 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   (no managed stack frames)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] 
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] "HeapTaskDaemon" prio=5 tid=9 WaitingForTaskProcessor
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x132c0750 self=0xdd584610
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=22039 nice=4 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xbd6701e0
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=S schedstat=( 1740376612 449504217 1458 ) utm=116 stm=57 core=0 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xbd56d000-0xbd56f000 stackSize=1040KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes=
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00000b97  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+7)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 0005ad68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (syscall+40)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 001d82ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+108)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 001d8273  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::Wait(art::Thread*)+35)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 0034a036  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::GetTask(art::Thread*)+630)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 0034aa64  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)+84)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #06 pc 005591f5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::VMRuntime_runHeapTasks(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+53)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:531)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2023-08-21 10:46:59.626 22025-22051 om.example.gam          com.example.game                     A  runtime.cc:655] 
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] "FinalizerDaemon" prio=5 tid=10 Waiting
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x132c0318 self=0xdd587010
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=22041 nice=4 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xbd45e1e0
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=S schedstat=( 27091640 2409459 226 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=0 HZ=100
```

What makes this problem realy strange is that when using another png file as the drawable, everything works fine. For example when using this png file [image: Thermometer] everything works without any problems or if I just use an Android internal image or vector asset. So the code itself is correct. But when using the window png file[image: Window] I get this strange error. I created both PNG files by using the very same program (Inkscape). They are both orignially vector graphics and I converted them into png by using Inkscape. So my question is does anyone have a clue why Android has problems with the self-made window image but not with the self-made thermometer image?